# AsyncTask onPostExecute() is not called from Fragment class but works in Activity class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-asynctask

This is for the first time I'm getting an issue with the AsyncTask onPostExecute(). I have other AsyncTask working in Fragment. For this specific fragment class, the AsyncTask **doInBackground() complets its execution**, but the **onPostExecute() is not called**. I tried returning the data from **doInBackground** as well as assigning to a **global variable** in AsyncTask. But for both the cases, the **onPostExecute** didn't call.

Here is my code snippet.

```
private void downloadFeedsAndTweets() {  
    new DownloadTwitterAsyncTask().execute("ScreenName"); // ScreenName is the proper screen name. 
    new DownloadInstagramFeedAsyncTask().execute("Instagram_URL");  //Instagram_URL is the actual url.
}

public class DownloadInstagramFeedAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
  List<InstagramData> instagramFeeds = null;

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
        // calls http request to get the feeds
        instagramFeeds = instagramFeedParser(JsonObject);
        Log.d(TAG, "DownloadInstagramFeedAsyncTask instagramFeeds received");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // show the feeds in ui using the variable instagramFeeds if != null.
  }

  private List<InstagramData> instagramFeedParser(JSONObject object) throws JSONException, IOException {
    // parse the json and returns the list
    return instagarmFeedList;
  }
}

public class DownloadTwitterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
  List<TwitterTweet> twitterTweets = null;

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    if (params.length > 0) {
        // retrieves twitter tweets and assigns to variable twitterTweets.
        twitterTweets = twitterAPI.getTwitterTweets(params[0]);
        Log.e(TAG, "DownloadTwitterAsyncTask tweet received");
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    // update ui with the twitter tweets using variable twitterTweets if != null.
  }
}
```

The same code **works if called from activity**. In fragment the **onPostExecute is not called for both the asyncTasks**.

Comment: How do you understand that the `onPostExecute()` is not being called?

Comment: return null? Might be the culprit? Try to debug using a log in onPostExecute

Comment: Is here any reason you are not returning `List<InstagramData>` in `doInBackground()`? Setting it to a field is not thread safe. It might just be possible that the worker thread has set the field, but the ui thread is not seeing the changed value.

Comment: Also you seem to nest the `AsyncTask` without making it static, that creates a memory leak.

Comment: @hrskrs: i added a log befor super call in onPostExecute, it didn't get printed.

Comment: @Skynet: i tried both by returning null and by returning the List as well. But for both the case the onPostExecute is not called.

Comment: Did you debug? Use a log statement. Question does not arise that onPostExecute will not be called after doInBackground();

Comment: @Xaver Kapeller: i didn't get you. The AsyncTask class is a seperate java file.

Comment: @Skynet: yeah, i debugged it.

Comment: I called the downloadFeedsAndTweets() at end of onCreateView()  before returning the view of Fragment class.

Comment: Try calling `new DownloadInstagramFeedAsyncTask().execute("Instagram_URL");` on `onPostExecute()` of `DownloadTwitterAsyncTask`. And please `Debug`. Thats the easiest way to figure out your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**..Inside onActivityCreated(),there is a while loop whose condition will fail after the onPostExecute() is completed. If am not wrong, I think because of this while loop, the onPostExecute is remained in the main thread and waits for onActivityCreated to be finished.